# Create legend with non-linear scale in base R

Tags: r

I'm using the base R functions to create a map with a legend and sub-regions of the map are coloured according to a value that I've provided in a dataframe (`new_df$foi`).

Here is my code for making the map with the legend:

```
library(maptools)
library(plyr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(fields)
library(raster)
suppressMessages(library(rgdal))
library(RColorBrewer)

#Determine breaks for colour
mybreaks= seq(0,max(new_df$foi),by = 0.01)


#Create palette
cols <- (colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(6,"OrRd"))(length(mybreaks)-2))
mycols<- c("grey90",cols)
#Match data with breaks
vcols = findInterval(c(new_df$foi),mybreaks)

#Plot
par(mar=c(0,0,2,4.5),oma=c(1,1,1,1))
plot(shapefile,col="grey90")
plot(shapefile[shapefile$code %in% new_df$code,],col=mycols[vcols],add=TRUE)

image.plot(legend.only=T,breaks=mybreaks,labels=mybreaks,col=mycols,legend.cex=1,cex=1,
           axis.args = list(cex.axis = 1),legend.width=1.2,legend.shrink = .6)
```

This works fine because the breaks (stored in the vector mybreaks) follow a linear scale. However I want the breaks to follow a non-linear scale. When I change the breaks to this:

```
mybreaks = c(seq(0,0.1, by = 0.01),seq(0.1,max(new_df$foi), by = 0.1))
```

and rerun the code the map is plotted successfully but I get the following warning:

```
Error in image.default(ix, iy, iz, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "",  : 
  increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected
```

and the legend is missing from the plot.

Can anyone tell me how to get the legend to display with a non-linear colouring scale. Would prefer answers using base R for ease of implementation but if anyone has an answer using ggplot2 or something else that would be great also.

Comment: `new_df` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer for ggplot. If you want a legend with a discrete scale, you'll have to specify in your aesthetics what you want it to color by. You'll also have to tell it to treat it as a factor if it's a continuous variable, which is what that "factor()" wrap is doing. Then you'll also include scale_fill_manual() with your values specified, or possibly "scale_color_discrete()" can be modified somehow in the ggplot setup. I know scale_color_discrete works for points and bars, etc., it may need to be modified for a fill color.

ggplot(data, aes(x, y, group = foo, fill = factor(foo2)) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "red", "grey"))